# Detecting Cache Misses and Hits Pragmatically in Linux

Tags: c, linux, caching

I know this is platform-specific question, however, I would like to do some run-time analysis of an application to detect cache misses and hits.  I know cachegrind, a tool for valgrind, and of vtune, and that a slew of other profiling utilities exist.  However, I am interested, in implementing my own version of cache-miss detection.  I know cachegrind acts as a cache-simulator.  Without hacking apart the kernel, how can I detect a cache-miss pragmatically?  I have a feeling this is nearly impossible for a user-land application, but I had to ask anyways.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I detect a cache-miss pragmatically [without cache simulation]?

Caches are managed by hardware - not the kernel. Their parameters (levels of cache, size, kick-out policy, write-back/write-through, etc.) are all processor implementation-specific. As a programmer you're "not supposed to know they exist". Thus, to measure cache-miss performance without cache simulation is impossible.

On the other hand VM pages (a *much* coarser "cache" - in the sense that a cache holds chunks of memory) are managed by the OS. I imagine there would be ways to gather statistics about page faults by hacking at the kernel or even creating a nifty user application. Page fault statistics may not be *that* much of use to you (especially since they're affected by other running processes), but an application using large amounts of RAM *might* (a teeny, tiny bit) have page-fault or page-access patterns similar to CPU cache access patterns. However, I'm not so sure about the details.

Comment: Aye, good point.  I do know that the kernel initializes the paging system when the kernel loads.  I should possibly have asked more about page hits/misses.

Comment: Well but many processors seem to be able to report cache-misses etc. For example perfex uses this: http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/anton/linux-perfex/ppc7450.html But it also needs to patch the kernel.

Comment: @advait: Your answer regarding measuring cache misses is wrong. CPUs implement [hardware performance counters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_performance_counter) which can be read by software. This is crucial if you want to optimize your software's cache behavior.

Answer (score 5):

There is a way to do this! On Linux you can exploit the Linux Performance Counter Subsystem for this purpose. E.g. have a look here: http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.37.3/tools/perf/